# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' when trying to built an Onboarding Screen Android Studio (liquid swipe)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0] C:\Users\moham.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1105262a3bbe137895b6e5bbba256874\jetified-liquid-swipe-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.cuberto.liquid_swipe" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 399ms
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-datea

Comment: `Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21, or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.cuberto.liquid_swipe" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)`

Answer (score -2):

Add this code in your manifest

```
<manifest 
    ... >
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.cuberto.liquid_swipe"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: This sounds like it'll at best silence the warning but not actually fix anything. Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yeah It is a bad idea I know, but this is working for me that's why I Answered and if he wants to use the library he should set his minSdk to 21

Comment: In that case giving some context and/or explanation instead of just blindly posting a dangerous suggestion would be in order. For example, you could explain in your answer what it does and how it can go wrong. Simply posting this without comment is counter-productive (it will just cause the problem to show up at runtime which is much harder to track down).